# How to simulate flip flop noise

Tags: noise, flipflop, comparator, thermal

Or is flip flop noisy at all? would you simluate its noise as you would do with a [strong arm comparator](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/brweb/papers/Journals/BR_Magzine4.pdf)?
Why is strong arm comparator noisy but not a flip flop?

Comment: Hi, Emerald,  I don't think this concept of "noisiness" is usually applied to a digital device.  You are using it oddly, so you will have to explain what you mean by "noisy", then perhaps your question could be answered.

Comment: a FlipFlop draws surge curents, perhaps as large as 0.01 amps that turns on and off in about 1 nanosecond. Any inductance in the VDD will cause VDD collapse and perhaps cause the FF to incorrectly change state. Also, the various transistors inside the FF will change their operating conditions, and be an  AMPLIFIER (of the transistor internal noise, and the noise on VDD), which causes output timing jitter noise. What is your situation?

Comment: hi @user69795 the thermal noise of the devices will change the timing of the output data, right? that's what i am referring to as "noisy" behavior

Comment: @analogsystemsrf yes i am referring to output timing jitter noise but the one caused by the thermal noise of the flip flop transistor devices